# How can I allow multiple @JmsListener destinations for a single method

Tags: java, spring-boot, jms, spring-jms

I'm currently working on migrating an IBM Webshere application to Spring Boot.

As part of this there is an MDB class which needs to be converted into `@JmsListener`. This MDB has a single method that is listening to multiple queues. I would like to do the same using `@JmsListener` with multiple destinations. I saw [this thread](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/17738), but that's not working.

This is the current MDB Configuration :

Bean 1

```
<bean id="myAppabcResponseMDB" class="company.myApp.service.mdb.MyAppMessageListenerMDB"/>
    <bean id="jmsContainer" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory"/>
        <property name="destination" ref="myAppabcResponseDest"/>
        <property name="messageListener" ref="myAppabcResponseMDB"/>
        <property name="maxConcurrentConsumers" value="5"/>
        <property name="sessionTransacted" value="true"/>
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
        <property name="taskExecutor" ref="myTaskExecutor" />
      </bean>
      <bean id="myAppabcResponseDest" name="jms/myAppESBResponse" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="jms/myAppabcResponse"/>
        <property name="resourceRef" value="true"/>
      </bean>
```

---

```
<bean id="myAppRequestMDB" class="company.myApp.service.mdb.MyAppMessageListenerMDB"/>
  <bean id="jmsContainer2" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory"/>
    <property name="destination" ref="myAppRequestDest"/>
    <property name="messageListener" ref="myAppRequestMDB"/>
    <property name="maxConcurrentConsumers" value="1"/>
    <property name="sessionTransacted" value="true"/>
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
    <property name="taskExecutor" ref="myTaskExecutor" />
  </bean>
  <bean id="myAppRequestDest" name="jms/myAppRequest" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="jms/myAppRequest"/>
    <property name="resourceRef" value="true"/>
  </bean>
```

Comment: I have updated the question with the current configuration.

Comment: I'm using Springboot 2.1.7

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@JmsListener is a repeatable annotation on Java 8, so you can associate several JMS destinations with the same method by adding additional @JmsListener declarations to it.

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#jms-annotated